# Safari Video Play on Event

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari, fullpage.js

I have several HTML5 videos on my page.

I am using [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage) and would like to trigger a different video playback depending on what slide you're on.

My code hides the old video and shows the new one in a fixed position container every time you scroll a slide. It looks basically something like this:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){

        $('#video1').hide();
        $('#video2').show();
        $('#video2')[0].play();
    }
});
```

This works great in every browser except Safari, which throws the following error, I think because of Safari's inbuilt protection against auto-playing ads.

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError (DOM Exception 35): The
>   request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the
>   current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

I am not fantastic at JS, but reading around it sounds like .play() has to be triggered on a click for it to be allowed. However, that won't work with what I'm trying to achieve. does anyone know how I can achieve a the play() based on the onLeave event?

Comment: Note:  triggering playback on a button click works, but triggering a 'click' on that button doesn't have any effect.